# Always keep one specific row on top while sorting the others as usual

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, datasource

I've got an aspx with a GridView component.

My requirement is to always keep one specific row on top while sorting the others as usual, i.e. by clicking the header.

I tried with the OnSorting tag but regardless of what order I feed it into the datasource it does it's own resort anyway.

How to override this behavior, so that when the header is clicked I do the sorting in the codebehind myself, ignoring the gridview sorting?

EDIT:

```
GridView.DataSource = list.OrderBy(x => x.type).Select(....
GridView.DataBind();`
```

Comment: The best option would be to sort your data set/table before binding to the GridView with your business logic.

Comment: That's what I do but the built in sorting still takes place afterwards `regardless of what order I feed it into the datasource it does it's own resort`

Comment: The initial sort is fine but even if I do the same ordering in OnSorting (after clikcing on the header), it gets sorted by that column.

Answer (score 0):

**Initially.**

- Remove your special row from the list. and keep it separately.
- sort the list.
- bind data.
- Insert your special row at 0 place of grid view

**Then**

`DataGridView.Sorted` event

- Remove your special row from gridview
- Insert your special row at 0 place of grid view.

Comment: Would work I guess but I was trying to keep this to a single LINQ query without removing/re-adding - to keep it tidy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot figure out what it was. But repeated full rebuild solved this for me...